# How to add a character to decorate the numbers of an ordered list in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-lists

It's common practice in math textbooks to add an asterisk to indicate a difficult exercise. And occasionally you'll even see a double-asterisk or a dagger to indicated a *really* tough exercise.

[image: Example of a starred and non-starred exercise]

What's the cleanest way to get this same effect on a webpage? I hope that there's a nice way to do this with just CSS, so the HTML can look like this:

```
<ol>
    <li> Easy Exercise </li>
    <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
</ol>
```

For anyone interested, here's the [TeX.SE version of this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78398/52612).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution if you want asterick next to number, and also for double digits

```css
ul {
  background-color: red;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li.hard:before {
  content: "*";
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
}

li.hard:nth-of-type(n+10):before {
  left: -33px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>

</ol>
```

Comment: This works charmingly well. Thank you! I'm surprised though, that there isn't a more elegant way to do this than by adding the asterisk after the number, then moving it with a negative shift.

Comment: Indeed. Unfortunately there is no way to target the ordered list's numbers with css right now, otherwise we could place the :before on that number instead. But yea perhaps someone else has a more elegant solution

Comment: Oooh, interesting note, if instead of a character like "*" you use an HTML entity like `&sstarf;`, it'll display the literal text `&sstarf;` instead of a star. You wouldn't happen to know a fix for this, would you?

Comment: Yea use the unicode version,  22C6, and also have to escape it so `content: "\22C6";`

Answer (score 2):

To get the symbol out in front of the item number, you can use the following CSS that styles the counters from scratch. By setting `display: block;` it no longer automatically generates list item numbers and then you can use the `::before` selector to insert those yourself. A little bit of beautification might be needed afterwards.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}
li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "  " counter(item) ".";
  counter-increment: item;
  width: 2em;
  white-space: pre;
}
li.hard::before {
  content: "*" counter(item) ".";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `ol` class `custom-counter` to get the numbers for each row instead of the standard numbers `li` gives. This is so we can append that * before the #

```html
 
<style>
  .custom-counter {
     margin-left: 0;
     padding-right: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
   }
   .custom-counter li {
     counter-increment: step-counter;
   }

   .custom-counter li::before {
     content: ""counter(step-counter)".";
 left: 28px;
  position: absolute;
   }
   li.hard:before { 
     content: "*"counter(step-counter)".";
    left: 20px;
     
     
   }
</style>
   
<ol class="custom-counter">
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li class="hard"> Hard Exercise </li>
  <li> Easy Exercise </li>

</ol>
```

Comment: hope it helps out!

Comment: This appears to put the asterisk before the *content* of the list item instead of before the item number. So it comes out looking like `2. * Hard Exercise`. Is there a way to put the asterisk before the number itself?

Comment: @MikePierce Oh whoops my bad, lemme look

Comment: @MikePierce Heres a fixed version:)

Comment: Now how do you right-align the counter using `custom-counter`? Align it along the period?

Comment: @MikePierce I added a `position:absolute` on all of them and then did a specific `left:28px;` to line em up